# How to avoid ManytoManyField type?

Tags: django, database-design

I have my 3 models:

```
class POmaterial(models.Model):
    material = models.ForeignKey(Material, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    UOM = models.ManyToManyField(UOM, null=True, blank=True)
    PO = models.ForeignKey(PO, on_delete=models.PROTECT,blank=True, null=True)

class Material(models.Model):
    ############
    ######

class UOM(models.Model):
    material = models.ForeignKey(Material, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

I have used ManytoMany field type in UOM  in my POmaterial model since I want to be able to create my POMaterial for the same UOM few times if required however I saw a lot of times statements that it is not recommended to use ManyToMany relation in Django. I was wondering what are the alternatives in my case?

Comment: Has Django changed since I last used it? Why does everyone think you're supposed to avoid M2M relations now? How do you represent M2M relations, then? Or how do you refactor them away when they do exist? IF you're not supposed to use it, why does Django have a class explicitly to support it that is not deprecated?

Comment: Unfortunately after 30 minutes Google searching for your claim that **"it is not recommended to use ManyToMany relation in Django"**, I could not find a good article to justify that claim. Would you mind sharing the statements that you read.

Comment: Although I found couple article talking about Many To Many in traditional SQL, but none is particularly complaining about Django M2M implementation. And in Fact you should use it to ease up your development process.

Comment: He probably heard that it was bad to use many to many relationships when designing a database (without creating a third association table), not specific to Django.

Comment: http://www.joshuakehn.com/2013/6/23/django-m2m-modelform.html

Comment: @JohnGoldman That's not saying to avoid Django's M2M. It's saying that the default widget (which is replaceable) is a bad user experience, and that there may be some gotchas with ModelForms, which you may not even be using.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist that article does say "Many-to-many relationships are best avoided if at all possible" seems to be a misinformed or in experienced writer. one of the dangers of treating everything one reads on the web as the gospel truth